# Embeddinator-4000 : Method is getting ignored while generating .aar in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, embeddinator

I am using visual studio 17 (Windows) and trying to build a .aar file from a Xamarin C# Android Library using embeddinator-4000 tool, but the method using user defined class in parameter or return type is getting ignored by tool and not coming as part of .aar
Below is the 2 classes used :

1. Custom Class which extend ArrayList.

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Util;


namespace CalculationAndroid
{
    [Register("mono.embeddinator.android.ViewSubclass")]
    public class ViewSubclass : ArrayList
    {
        [Export("ViewSubclass")]
        public ViewSubclass() : base() { }
    }
}
```

2. Class in which the method using the ViewSubclass in parameter.

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Interop;

namespace CalculationAndroid
{
    [Register("mono.embeddinator.android.UseViewSubclass")]
    public class UseViewSubclass
    {
        [Export("store")]
        public void Store(ViewSubclass arrayList)
        {
            arrayList.Add("aaa");
            System.Console.WriteLine(arrayList.Get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

3. The class as shown in the .aar file (Decompiled).

```
package calculationandroid.calculationandroid;

import mono.embeddinator.*;
import com.sun.jna.*;

public class UseViewSubclass {
    public com.sun.jna.Pointer __object;

    public UseViewSubclass(com.sun.jna.Pointer object) { this.__object = object; }

    public UseViewSubclass() {
        __object = calculationandroid.Native_CalculationAndroid.INSTANCE.CalculationAndroid_UseViewSubclass_new();
        mono.embeddinator.Runtime.checkExceptions();
    }
}
```

Please help in figuring out, why the method **Store** is not being taken as a part of .aar file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your description and code, there is not Store method in .arr file, now you want to use .arr in project and call Store method?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for days.

The issue is with Types.
Try using basic array instead of arraylist and most probably your Store() method will not get ignored and will show up in the generated lib.

There are a number of limitations like these.
However, a complete list of limitations is not there.
Embeddinator 4000 is a great concept, but there has to be more documentation on how to build, use and interpret/fix errors in its generation log.

Hope this helps.